# Converting GRIB to CSV or to binary data

Tags: raster, convert, grib

**The challenge is to extract multidimensional data (weather and ocean data in this case) from .grib files, without having to**

1. download **and install** any new software on the computer by running installation programs,
2. download **and compile** any new source code,
3. rely on **pre-installed software** on the computer (like java, python or installation packages)

so that

1. Windows 10 is supported (without Linux emulators),
2. float64 is supported,
3. **it does it "bulk"**, ie. not only one record ("band") at time (which can take a full day for a large dataset, at speed of for example 1 band/second). Instead, it shall do the full extract with one single command (or only a handful of commands), and
4. it outputs the data from the grib to a named file, as binary or as readable ASCII.

**Ie. needing a downloadable command-line tool(set) that (after virus testing) extracts the data from .grib files, for further processing!**

**The GRIB format**

> GRIB (GRIdded Binary or General Regularly-distributed Information in
> Binary form[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB)) is a concise data format commonly used in meteorology
> to store historical and forecast weather data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous packages available on the net (see the wikipedia page in the question) but after two days of investigating practically everything I could find, there was only one good tool (fit for me) available:

[NOAA / The Climate Prediction Center's (CPC)](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/) and it's [wgrib](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib.html) or [wgrib2](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/index.html) tool.

(I have only tried wgrib, and the grib data is [Copernicus ERA5 ECMWF reanalysis](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=overview)).

The **wgrib** tool is a handful of downloadable files including one executable. Seems one can place them in any directory and the .exe (compiled in 2017) runs autonomously. The documentation is good.

The command line

```
wgrib source.grib | -i source.grib -text -nh -o target.txt
```

will write a concatenation of the multidimensional grib-file's data values as readable text (one value per row) into target.txt.

The command line

```
wgrib source.grib | -i source.grib -bin -nh -o target.bin
```

will write a concatenation of the same as binary into target.bin.

There are multiple options.

---

In response to @xunilks's comment, I'm adding some detail about the output formats of the conversion.

Example: If the grib file contains the following dimensions:

1. latitude (0.25 degree intervals)
2. longitude (0.25 degree intervals)
3. time (one hour interval)

with the following cell data

1. Wind U component
2. Wind V component
3. Significant wave height

and the dimensional spans are

1. latitude; 10-11 degrees (with 0.25 deg intervals, gives 1x4+1 = 5 values; 10, 10.25, 10.5, 10.75, 11)
2. longitude; 45-47 degrees (with 0.25 deg intervals, gives 2x4+1 = 11 values; 45, 45.25, 45.5, 45.75, 46, 46.25, 46.5, 46.75, 47)
3. time; 25.7 2020 - 27.7 2020 (one hour intervals, gives 2x24+1 = 49 values)

then there will be an output of 5x11x49 = 2695 cells and each cell will contain 3 numbers (windu, windv, waveh). Hence, the total number of numbers in the data file will be 2695x3 = 8085. wgrib writes them either as a readable text file (with 8085 rows) or a binary file of 32-bit (=4 byte) floats (note: not 64-bit, unfortunately, so we get 7 significants instead of 14 - not a huge problem), hence the file size will be 8085x4 = 32340 bytes.

(For example in C#, one can use [BitConverter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=netcore-3.1) to convert bytes into float-32's)

The order seems to be (time(data(lat(lon)))) repetitions, where data consists of windu,windv,waveh. This means that

- the first 11x5=55 numbers in the binary (or text) file are windu values for the 1st hour, as a concatenation of lon columns and lat rows.
- the second 11x5=55 numbers (ie. numbers 56-110) are windv values for the 1st hour, same concatenation
- the third 55 numbers are waveh values for the first hour, ...
- the fourth 55 numbers are windu values for the second hour, ...
- the fifth 55 numbers are windv values for the second hour, ...
- etc.

wgrib writes a nice housekeeping file that shows detail about the order of the written numbers. In Windows, one gets that into a text file by adding >[filename] to the command line, eg.

```
wgrib source.grib | -i source.grib -text -nh -o target.txt >myindexhelpfile.txt
```

See wgrib documentation!